# AddChildAt() to add item at specific index position

Tags: actionscript-3, flex4

I have a textBox and I am using it as a mail address input field where the user can type in several addresses, a bit same as in hotmail. Each address is rendered into a clickable button. Thus upon double-clicking on a specific address I want the item to be editable. After having edited the address when the user taps enter, the item is added to the list of mail adds.

I am adding it using the code below:

flowBox.addChildAt( myItem, myindex);

However addChildAt seems to add the item as the last item in the list. But I want it to add the item the position where it was originally. Say the item was at position 2 in the mail list, after editing adn tapping enter, it should add at position 2 itself and not at the end of the list.

Can you please tell me if there is any way for doing this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use `addElementAt()` instead. More details are [here](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf62b90-7fe9.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can do what Constantiner has suggested, perhaps it's addChildAt(index).

The other way of doing is just hide the child and show the child instead by visible property instead of removing and adding

Comment: Tried it..didnt work. addElementAt() works better. Thx though.